# How can i publish a message to a list using facebook's graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After a user has provided me their oauth credentials, I would like to allow them to post a message to a group of their friends.

Say they have created a list of 10 friends and called it "My soccer buddies", I now want to be able to allow them to POST a message to their list "My soccer buddies" from within my web application using the graph api.

How would I do this ?

Looking at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post it seems to be possible by providing the "To" parameter but than in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing it says you must post to

/PROFILE_ID/feed - desc: - write to the given profile's feed/wall - args: - message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source

Note the To param is not available in args above.

So how could this be done?

Also: What is the reccomended way for a web app using the graph api to allow a user to send send a message to 10 of his friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible. The new groups feature however provides access via the graph api and could be looked into as an alternative.